# Set "charm" icon for Outlook365 using Power Automate or MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to create events in Outlook365 calender where I specify the category and the charm icon (i.e. phone icon for calls, repair icon for tasks, etc.; as they are available in the calendar in the browser) using PowerAutomate or the Graph-API.

An event with a charm would look like this.

[image]

At least I managed to set the category using a HTTP patch request when following the guide here: https://www.cloudappie.nl/lowcode-categorize-meetings-outlook/

I tried to set the charm icon the same way, but I wasn't able to find the appropriate keyword or any other way to set the charm icon in the [MS Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body).

The only other resource I was able to find, and that is closest to what I try to do, was [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2169), but that issue was closed with the hint to ask on stackOverflow... and I cannot find anything as as related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get and set the Charm in the Graph using Extended properties as there is no strongly typed value for this. eg to get the charms on item use

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer {11000E07-B51B-40D6-AF21-CAA85EDAB1D0} Id 0x27')

and if you want to set one you use

```html
{
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "Integer {11000e07-b51b-40d6-af21-caa85edab1d0} Id 0x27",
            "value": "Car"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know of any documented list of values for charm so you just need to find the value from an existing item where its set.

While the above works okay there is some weirdness in the Graph around this property that could be considered a bug. Eg the property in question is a Integer property and if you look at it in MAPI it has a integer value. Requesting and setting in using the Graph requires and returns a string which it shouldn't do based on it property type.

Comment: Works like a charm. I was sure that there is a MAPI property but it's impossible to find any documentation.

Comment: I've found out that for some icons like bike, bus, gym, island the query returns value "None"

Answer (score 0):

***Edit**: Ignore my suggested answer below. Like mentioned in the comments below I misunderstood the requirement. The charm icon field is something different than an icon in the subject field or the categories field.*

You should be able to use the same approach as in the link you already shared from Albert-Jan Schot.

Try the below body payload in a Send an HTTP request (Office 365 groups connector).

```
    {
      "subject": " Prep second recording trigger flow",
      "categories": ["Travel"]
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the expected result. The charm icon should be displayed next to event subject. On the left side of subject (Prep Second recording...). Probably the best solution right now :)

Comment: That is the solution from Albert-Jan Schot. As far as I am reading it the OP doesn't want to use the icon in the subject field but in the category field.

Comment: @Expiscornovus: Thank you for you answer. But user2250152 statement is correct, I want to set the "charm" icon, which is the icon left of the subject.

Comment: Wow, I needed a bit of coffee to realise what the charm icon was. I totally misunderstood the requirement, my bad.